# Create crystal report by joining two tables vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I need to create a report summary, I have two tables named borrowers_information and loan_information.
[See tables.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXjW6.png)
Below is the code I have tried But I don't get any data. [See here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F97Ae.png)
The query works fine in the workbench.

```
    Dim adapt As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataSet

    Dim printQuery As String = "select * from borrowers_information inner join loan_information on borrowers_information.borrowerid = loan_information.borrowerid"
    openConnection()
    com = New MySqlCommand(printQuery, getDBCon)
    adapt.SelectCommand = com
    adapt.Fill(dt)

    Dim report As New BalanceReport
    report.SetDataSource(dt)
    frmPreviewBalanceReport.reportBalance.ReportSource = report
    frmPreviewBalanceReport.reportBalance.Refresh()
```

If I only choose from one table I get data on the report by using this code:

```
    Dim adapt As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataSet

    Dim printQuery As String = "select * from borrowers_information"
    openConnection()
    com = New MySqlCommand(printQuery, getDBCon)
    adapt.SelectCommand = com
    adapt.Fill(dt, "borrowers_information")
    Dim report As New BalanceReport
    report.SetDataSource(dt)
    frmPreviewBalanceReport.reportBalance.ReportSource = report
    frmPreviewBalanceReport.reportBalance.Refresh()
```

Comment: Not sure about the Crystal reports side of things, but your query includes a field (borrowerid) that is present in both tables. You could try to alias that field, or better yet don't do `select *` but pick only the fields you need. The fields can also be prefixed with the table name to eliminate ambiguity.

Comment: I already tried that but no luck

Comment: There is not much point to the join since you haven't retrieved any fields from the second table or used a field from the second table in a Where clause.

Comment: I think this query "select * from borrowers_information inner join loan_information on borrowers_information.borrowerid = loan_information.borrowerid" will do the job since in the workbench it works just fine. but in crystal report I only get blank data

Comment: I solved it. The problem was in the .xsd file that I created. When I'm getting my table using database expert I always choose the two tables (borrowers_information & loan_information) now I only choose one table. I configured the table adapter in .xsd file using join the join query. Problem solved